# Distribute a Qt5 console application using CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I fruitlessly tried to distribute a basic Qt console application by using CMake.

Let's consider these 2 files:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << "Hello Wolrd!";
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

project(HelloWorld)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Widgets)
```

Next I compile the `main.cpp` file doing:

```shell
$ cmake .

-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/HelloWorld

$ make

Scanning dependencies of target HelloWorld_autogen
[ 25%] Automatic MOC for target HelloWorld
[ 25%] Built target HelloWorld_autogen
Scanning dependencies of target HelloWorld
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/HelloWorld_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable HelloWorld
[100%] Built target HelloWorld
```

And I get a `HelloWorld` binary file.

The problem comes when I try to execute the latter file on another computer which don't have Qt installed. I get this bellow error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
  Referenced from: /path/to/HelloWorld/./HelloWorld
  Reason: image not found
./test.sh: line 4: 68737 Abort trap: 6           ./HelloWorld
```

What is missing to make this working as a standalone application?

**Environment:**

- MacOs Mojave (10.14.4)
- Qt 5.10.1

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/osx-deployment.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to link Qt statically. Check out the documentation about [deploying for macOS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/macos-deployment.html).

Be aware that Qt is licensed under the LGPL, which may have implications for static linking. Check out [this FAQ](https://www.qt.io/faq/#_Toc_3_7) for details.

You could also use bundles and frameworks, but I'm not sure how well that works with console applications.